# issue sending magento order confirmation emails

Tags: php, magento, email

we had an issue with our sendmail program recently. for some reason it wasn't working. i ended up fixing it, but we're still not receiving confirmation emails from the store. it doesn't give us an error (as far as i can tell), but it simply isn't sending. is there anywhere somebody could suggest i look to fix it? log files, PHP files, anything? i'm at a loss and i've been working on this for 2 days with no results. the client is getting more and more impatient.

the email user is receiving all other emails, the sendmail program is working properly, etc. I have no clue what could be wrong. can somebody at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try to configure custom SMTP is System > Configuration > System > Mail sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the fallow steps to trouble shoot the problem

1. run this command in the server:

   echo "This is a test." | mail -s Testing someone@somedomain.com
2. check is the email daemon is working
3. check the email log server at /var/logs/sendmail this depend of your enail server software
4. try this configuration

   Go to System > Configuration > ADVANCED > System > Mail Sending Settings

   Disable Email Communications = No

   Host = I changed it from localhost to mail.mydomain.com

   Port (25) = 25

   Set Return-Path = No

Good Luck

Comment: thanks. i did this and it eventually lead to the solution. the sendmail path in php.ini was /usr/bin/sendmail but it was actually in /usr/sbin/sendmail.